# Calling instance method of class from another another containing only self

Tags: python-3.x, class, self

```
class Cust(object):

    def __init__(self,cust_id,cust_day,cust_amt):
        self.id=cust_id
        self.total=0
        self.days=[cust_day]
        self.amounts=[cust_amt]


    def add_Purchases(self,day,amount):
        self.amounts.append(amount)
        self.days.append(day)
        print("add Purchase Executed for ",self.id,self.amounts)
        print(self.get_Total_Sales())

    def get_Total_Sales(self):
        total = sum(self.amounts)
        return total


class DB(object):

    def __init__(self,filedir):
        self.dir=filedir
        self.DB_cust={}
        self.createDatabase(filedir)    

    def importFile(self,file):
        file.readline() 
        for line in file:
            val=line.split(",") 

            customerID=data[0]
            if customerID in self.DB_cust:
                self.DB_cust[customerID].add_Purchases(val[2],float(val[3]))
            else:
                self.DB_cust[customerID]=Cust(val[0],val[1],val[2],float(val[3]))
```

I am trying to get the ID for `maximum value of total`. I call  `get_total_sales()` from the instance method in DB class `get_Max_ID()`

```
def get_Max_ID(self):
    print("Max Sale ID here")
    Cust.get_Total_Sales()
```

This obviously results in

> TypeError: get_Total_Sales() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

If I pass `self` through get_Max_ID. It would pass the self of DB and not Cust. I am not sure how to pass the self of Cust whilst calling it from DB class.

**Clarification** - The get_Total_Sales() gets the total for each customer but I am trying to get maximum value of total out of all the customer instances. (I have not written that part of code which draws maximum total)

Comment: @PirateX have you tried my updated answer?  You aren't initializing the `cust` class, hence your error.

Comment: @CalebGoodman `Cust` is being called from within `DB` via `self.DB_cust[customerID]=Cust(data[0],data[1],data[2],float(data[3]))`

Comment: @PirateX Yes and since you have multiple `Cust` objects in that dictionary, the question remains: *Which* of these `Cust`'s `get_Total_Sales()` do you want to have?

Comment: @uneven_mark The one with maximum value. If there are 3 customers having total of  5,10 and 15. I want the 15.

Comment: @PirateX So really you want to call `get_Total_Sales()` on each of the `Cust` in the dictionary and then return the one with the highest value?

Comment: @PirateX   You pass in `self` to a class upon initialization.  One way or another, you will have to *initialize* your `Cust` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by what OP says they want to do in the question comments, they probably want something like:

```
max([cust.get_Total_Sales() for id, cust in self.DB_cust.items()])
```

It will iterate over the dictionary of customers, and for each pair key/value pair (`id` and `cust`) will call and return that `Cust`'s `get_Total_Sales()`.

Then `max` will take all the individual results from the generated list of values and return only the maximum value.

As asked in the comment, although I see no reason not to use a comprehension:

```
results = []
for id, cust in self.DB_cust.items():
    results.append(cust.get_Total_Sales())
return max(results)
```

Comment: @PirateX Sorry, fixed it now.